# getopt() function - optind not incrementing/behaving as expected

Tags: c, command-line

Depending on the format with which I pass options to this program, the variable `optind` will either increment properly to reflect the next option value or it will not.

If I use `./cfind -aru`, I get the following (strange) output.

```
optind: 1
aflag detected
optind: 1
optind: 1
rflag detected
optind: 1
optind: 2
uflag detected
optind: 2
```

Notice that optind does not increment from aflag to rflag but it does increment from rflag to uflag.

However, when I use the format ./cfind -a -r -u, I get the following (expected) output.

```
optind: 2
aflag detected
optind: 2
optind: 3
rflag detected
optind: 3
optind: 4
uflag detected
optind: 4
```

This is the output I desire.

My code for this function is as follows.

```
#include "cfind.h"
#define OPTLIST "acdirstu" // list of valid options

void ProcOpt(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int opt = 0; // default value
    opterr = 0; // prevent getopt from passing error message to stderr buffer
    // char *filenm = NULL; // pointer to the path name
    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, OPTLIST)) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'a':
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
                aflag = true;
                assert(aflag == true);
                fprintf(stdout, "aflag detected\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
            break;      
            case 'c':
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
                cflag = true;
                assert(cflag == true);
                fprintf(stdout, "cflag detected\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
            break;      
            case 'd':
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
                dflag = true;
                assert(cflag == true);
                fprintf(stdout, "dflag detected\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
            break;      
            case 'i':
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
                iflag = true;
                assert(iflag == true);
                fprintf(stdout, "iflag detected\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
            break;      
            case 'r':
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
                rflag = true;
                assert(rflag == true);
                fprintf(stdout, "rflag detected\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
            break;      
            case 's':
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
                sflag = true;
                assert(sflag == true);
                fprintf(stdout, "sflag detected\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
            break;      
            case 't':
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
                tflag = true;
                assert(tflag == true);
                fprintf(stdout, "tflag detected\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
            break;      
            case 'u':
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);
                uflag = true;
                assert(uflag == true);
                fprintf(stdout, "uflag detected\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "optind: %i\n", optind);        
            break;
            default:
                usage();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something I am misunderstanding about `getopt()` and how it increments `optind`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output looks right to me.

`optind` is the index of the next argument to be processed. When you have all the options together, they're all in `argv[1]`, so `optind` remains at 1 until you've processed the `u` option. At that point, since everything in `argv[1]` has been consumed, `optind` is set to 2.

When the options are all in separate elements of `argv`, `optind` is always the index of the next argument to be processed.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html.

Answer (score 2):

The [getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) man page says (emphasis mine):

> The variable optind is the index of the next element to be processed **in argv**.

Your invocation options `-aru` are all contained as a single string in `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the start of your program to see what is going on:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
     printf("Param %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> #include <unistd.h>
      extern char *optarg;
      extern int optind;
      int main (int argc, char** argv) {
        int c;
      printf("--------- options: ---------\n");
      while ((c = getopt (argc,argv,"abcd:")) != -1) {
          printf("opt: %c arg %s\n", (char)c, optarg);
      }
      argc -= optind - 1;
      argv += optind - 1; 
      printf("------ remaining args: ------\n");
      for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]); 
     } 
    }
```